# Is there an iOS override for when a view was popped back?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a MasterDetail Application, and a NavButton to add a new item. Im am able to successfully pop the view back, however I need to reload the table nice that is done. So how exactly can my MasterViewController know when it was popped so it could reload?

Heres the Pop code:

```
NavigationController.PopViewController(true);
```

It functions as expected, I just then need MasterViewController to reload the table, which I made a method for:

```
public void ReloadTable()
{
    TableView.ReloadData ();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
public partial class MasterViewController : UIViewController
{
    public void ReloadTable()
    {
        TableView.ReloadData ();
    }
}



public partial class DetailViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        var masterViewController = NavigationController.ViewControllers.OfType<MasterViewController> ().FirstOrDefault();
        if (masterViewController != null) {
            masterViewController.ReloadTable ();
        }

        base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);
    }
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq;` to get the OfType method.

Comment: .OfType<>(); Doesn't seem to exist according to my debugger.

Comment: You will need to add using System.Linq; to your using statements. Also, I updated the code to include FirstOrDefault() at the end since the OfType method returns a collection.

Comment: After implementing that, it still doesn't reload the table data.

Comment: I figured it out now. I kept attempting to reload the data, but I forgot to add the new data to be reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

## Objective-C

It can be done by checking if navigationController contains viewcontroller like this:

**Note** `viewControllerA` pushes `viewControllerB`

Now in `viewControllerB` use `viewWillDisappear` method

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
  if (![[self.navigationController viewControllers] containsObject: self]) //any other hierarchy compare if it contains self or not
  { 
    // the view has been removed from the navigation stack or hierarchy, back is probably the cause
    // this will be slow with a large stack however.

    viewControllerA *objViewControllerA = [[self.navigationController viewControllers] lastObject];
    //NSLog(@"%@",objViewControllerA);
    if (objViewControllerA)
    {
        [objViewControllerA viewPoppedBack];
    }
  }
}
```

Now `add` one `method` in `viewControllerA`

```
 -(void)viewPoppedBack
 {
    //reload tableview here
    [yourTableViewHere reloadData];
 }
```

Comment: Do you know how this could be done in C# using Xamarin?